# Coq-ide on Fedora Scientific, no icons

Tags: fedora, gnome

I installed coq using `snap install coq-prover` on Fedora scientific ,it looks like this when I run command `coqide`

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us4lc.png)

I can't see icons I've read that is an issue of not having installed `gnome-icon-theme` however I don't have a clue how to do this on Fedora and set a proper configuration.
Also one of errors when launching `coqide` is `Error loading theme icon 'go-up' for stock: Brak ikony „go-up” w motywie Adwaita`
and a lot of similar ones referring to other icons.